# Problem with some css after update angular material to v15

Tags: angular, angular-material, intl-tel-input

In my angular project I have just updated material from 14 to 15.
Now I have a problem with the css of [ng2-tel-input](https://github.com/gauravsoni119/ng2-tel-input).
When I open the dropdown it seems under other material stuff and not on top like before upgrade
(the library is no longer updated so I can't ask to the creators).

I already tried with z-index, position etc but nothing worked, the problem affects only material components.
If you suggest me something I would be grateful.
[image]

Comment: Try `background: #fff` for the dropdown options.

Comment: background is already set in container and in options

Comment: Can you try to reproduce this in StackBlitz?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is caused by `will-change` css introduced in materia v15
Changed it to `will-change: auto`